# Excel templates can't be applied

Tags: excel, charts, excel-charts

On Excel 2013, when trying to change the chart type of a pivot chart to a template saved to the template folder I get the following error message:

> This template can't be applied. It's either damaged or won't work for the selected chart. Please try recreating it.

[Discussion without solution on technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0c49a055-2f9c-4ea0-8d7a-4b868e66ef8a/pivotcharts-and-templates)

It even occurs if I save a template and try applying it for the exact same graph. Any ideas?